# Django Exif Data: 'IFDRational' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django

I got an issue with the code:
'IFDRational' object is not subscriptable

Here is the trace:

```
lat = get_decimal_from_dms(geotags['GPSLatitude'], geotags['GPSLatitudeRef'])
degrees = dms[0][0] / dms[0][1]
```

the is issue is:
Variable    Value
dms
(45.0, 46.0, 34.29)
ref
'N'

```
{'GPSAltitude': 22.90324416619237,
 'GPSAltitudeRef': b'\x00',
 'GPSDateStamp': '2020:10:17',
 'GPSDestBearing': 18.1919587128,
 'GPSDestBearingRef': 'M',
 'GPSHPositioningError': 65.0,
 'GPSImgDirection': 108.199192887128,
 'GPSImgDirectionRef': 'M',
 'GPSLatitude': (12.0, 26.0, 14.09),
 'GPSLatitudeRef': 'N',
 'GPSLongitude': (1.0, 47.0, 39.38),
 'GPSLongitudeRef': 'E',
 'GPSSpeed': 0.0,
 'GPSSpeedRef': 'K',
 'GPSTimeStamp': (12.0, 58.0, 42.0)}
```

That what I get from an image for instance. I think the code assimilate GPSLatitudeRef to degrees = dms[0][0] / dms[0][1]. The thing is GPSLatitudeRef is a letter none a number.

```
def get_geotagging(exifgps):
    
        geotagging = {}
        for (idx, tag) in TAGS.items():
            if tag == 'GPSInfo':
                if idx not in exifgps:
                    raise ValueError("No EXIF geotagging found")
    
                for (key, val) in GPSTAGS.items():
                    if key in exifgps[idx]:
                        geotagging[val] = exifgps[idx][key]
    
        return geotagging
        
    def get_decimal_from_dms(dms, ref):

        degrees = dms[0][0] / dms[0][1]
        minutes = dms[1][0] / dms[1][1] / 60.0
        seconds = dms[2][0] / dms[2][1] / 3600.0
    
        if ref in ['S', 'W']:
            degrees = -degrees
            minutes = -minutes
            seconds = -seconds
    
        return round(degrees + minutes + seconds, 5)
        
    def get_lat_coordinates(geotags):
            lat = get_decimal_from_dms(geotags['GPSLatitude'], geotags['GPSLatitudeRef'])
            return lat
            
    def get_lon_coordinates(geotags):
            lon = get_decimal_from_dms(geotags['GPSLongitude'], geotags['GPSLongitudeRef'])
            return lon

try:
            exifgps = img.getexif()
            geotags = get_geotagging(exifgps)
            self.gpsinfo = geotags
        except Exception as e:
                pass
        
        #try:
        exifgps = img.getexif()
        geotags = get_geotagging(exifgps)
        self.latitude = get_lat_coordinates(geotags)
        #except Exception as e:
                #pass
        
        #try:
        exifgps = img.getexif()
        geotags = get_geotagging(exifgps)
        self.longitude = get_lon_coordinates(geotags)
        #except Exception as e:
                #pass
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot comprehend why `degrees = dms[0][0] / dms[0][1]` is necessary when you can simply extract degrees from the tuple using `degrees = dms[0]`

**Replace**

```
def get_decimal_from_dms(dms, ref):

    degrees = dms[0][0] / dms[0][1]
    minutes = dms[1][0] / dms[1][1] / 60.0
    seconds = dms[2][0] / dms[2][1] / 3600.0
```

**With**

```
def get_decimal_from_dms(dms, ref):

    degrees = dms[0]
    minutes = dms[1] / 60.0
    seconds = dms[2] / 3600.0
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to improve your answer.

Comment: That works well thanks. Could you please explain why?

Comment: It seems that with Pillow version 7 (and most likely below) the degree, minute and second values were tuples that were to be interpreted as fractions (the first value being the numerator and the second the denominator). 

Pillow version 8 provides just a number that can be used directly, which is why the change above is required.